# what is difference both where condition

Tags: sql-server

What is difference between both command, both are return same data.

Example

```
select * from EmployeeMstNew where 'ankit' = Name

select * from EmployeeMstNew where name = 'ankit'
```

Comment: No difference.. It is like `LHS = RHS`/  `RHS = LHS`

Comment: Do you have a question about the implementation details?  As you can see for yourself, logically it is the same.

Comment: no difference at all.

Comment: The only difference is in **readability**. `Name = 'ankit'` spontaneously implies that the filed in the table record called `Name` needs to be equal to `'ankit'`. The same is the other way, but (at least to my eyes), it is clearer when reading it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference.

Each condition in your WHERE statement is a boolean expression; in this scenario we are checking if the two string are the same, which they are.

Comment: ... or they are not, depending on the data of course.

Answer (score 0):

Typically in programming, assertions should be done from left to right.

Typically the syntax is;

```
where [FIELD] = 'PARAMETER'
```

Hope this clears things up!